# Are there any Distributed JDK's (JVM) around? (or Stub JDK or Remote JDK/JVM)

Tags: java, jvm, distributed

I want to know if there exist a way to use a JVM of a remote machine? \

For example I need to do some compilation on a not-so-powerful machine with not much CPU crunching power, like in my IntelliJ IDE I can select a JDK to use for a specific project. However there are times that the workstation cannot handle the compilation process and so forth.

Now I have a very powerful server in the network, plus other resources around. Is there a "stub" JDK that will actually call on a remote JDK from another machine?

Comment: it cant handle the compilation process but it can handle a java-based IDE? does that really exist?

Comment: Yes, if you compile a really huge Java app, like a Trading App made with GWT your PC can run out of resources

Comment: Why not use the usual ssh or similar OS-level use of another host's resources?

Comment: i have never seen a Java app which consume more resources to compile than to run a Java-based IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ... 

well, if you install something like Jenkins on the powerful server, you could upload your code to some control version system and ask Jenkins to do the building and war generation for you (and even deploy it on a Tomcat installed on that server).... this way, the only you would run locally would be the IDE.... you could point the JDK there in a network shared folder on the remote machine, but run the javac process in a remote machine i dont know if it is possible

Comment: @laune good idea, however I have not found any way for my other PC's to share resource to my machine